# Why is the jQuery selector not working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, jquery-selectors

I wonder why the jQuery selector by id isn't working here, when I'm trying to update the table cells after creating a hero. I'm using a basic jQuery selector but it doesn't do anything even with innerHTML. The jQuery selector is working on the input getting value function but not after that, it makes no sense to me and the console give me absolutely no errors.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-4 hero">
    <h2>Votre personnage</h2>
    <div>
        <h3>Créer un nouveau personnage</h3>
        <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Attention ! créer un nouveau personnage supprimera tout de l'ancien.</p>
        <label>Nom</label>
        <input type="text" id="hero_name_input" name="hero_name_input">
        <button>Créer personnage</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Les statistiques de votre personnage</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <td id="Hname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Habilité</th>
                <td id="Hskill"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Endurance</th>
                <td id="Hstamina"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Chance</th>
                <td id="Hluck"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.hero button').click( function create_hero() {
        let nom       = $('#hero_name_input').val(); // it works
        let habilite  = (roll_dice(1)+6);
        let endurance = (roll_dice(2)+12);
        let chance    = (roll_dice(1)+6);

        let hero = new Hero (nom, habilite, endurance, chance);
        //document.getElementById('Hname').innerHTML = hero.nom; // it works

        // not working block
        $('#Hname').html     = hero.nom;
        $('#Hskill').html    = hero.habilite.toString();
        $('#Hstamina').html   = hero.endurance.toString();
        $('#Hluck').html     = hero.chance.toString();
        // not working block
    });

    function roll_dice (dices) {
        if (dices == 1) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1)
        }
        else {
            let d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1)
            let d2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1)
            let dices_result = d1+d2;
            return dices_result;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `html()` is a method, not a property. See the docs: https://api.jquery.com/html

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#Hname').html(hero.nom);
```

This is the correct way to use jQuery's `.html()` function.

[jQuery html() docs](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, html is a function, so you must use `$('#Hname').html( hero.nom )`.